# Analytical solution of second order linear differential equation with boundary at infinity

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I am a new user to Mathematica and I would like to solve a simple second-order differential equation as follow:

$y''[x]+\frac{(D-1)}{x}\times y'[x]=k\times y[x]$,

where $D$ and $k$ are just two parameters and the boundary conditions are  $y[x=0]=A$ and $y[x=\infty]=0$.

How can I get an analytical solution for the equation with the boundary condition at infinity?

My attempt for the question looks like:

```
sol = DSolve[{y''[x] + (D - 1)*y'[x]/x == k*y[x], y[0] == A, y[Infinity] == 0}, y[x], x]
```

but the solver take the second input boundary condition as a 'True' argument.

Comment: `y[Infinity] == 0` is not a valid boundary condition.  Try using `DSolve[{y''[x] + (D - 1)*y'[x]/x == k*y[x]}, y[x], x] ` and then applying the boundary conditions after the fact.

Comment: I used `DSolve[{y''[x] + (D - 1)*y'[x]/x == k*y[x]}, y[x], x]` and I get the following result :
`{{y[x] ->   x^((2 - D)/2) BesselJ[1/2 (-2 + D), -I Sqrt[k] x] C[1] +  x^((2 - D)/2) BesselY[1/2 (-2 + D), -I Sqrt[k] x] C[2]}}`. 
After that how can I apply the boundary condition at infinity?

Comment: Try converting the Bessel functions into modified Bessel functions and then recall that only BesselK vanishes at infinity.

Comment: what is the value of `D` ? Btw, you should not use `D` but use `d`. I found the solution to be zero when `d>2`. otherwise, not defined.

Comment: @Nasser `D` is within the range from 0 to 1. Can you please show your method?

Comment: Part of Nasser's point is that `D` is the partial derivative operator and a protected symbol. It's best practice to avoid single-letter capitals for your own variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to get a fully automatic solution, but here is a human-assisted way:

This is a guess

```
Clear[ys]
ys[x_] := x^n  BesselK[n, Sqrt[k] x]
```

Does it work?

```
ys''[x] + (d - 1)*ys'[x]/x == k*ys[x] // FullSimplify
```

Seems so

```
(*Sqrt[k] (-2 + d + 2 n) x^n BesselK[-1 + n, Sqrt[k] x] == 0*)
```

But let us check the boundary conditions, taking into account $n=\frac{2-d}{2}$.

```
a=Assuming[k > 0 && n > 0, 
   Limit[ys[x], x -> 0]] /. {n -> (2 - d)/2} // Simplify
```

$$a=-2^{-\frac{d}{2}-1} d k^{\frac{d-2}{4}} \Gamma \left(-\tfrac{d}{2}\right)$$

Check the boundary condition at infinity

```
Assuming[k > 0 && n > 0, Limit[ys[x], x -> Infinity]]
(*0*)
```

Thus two boundary conditions are fulfilled and the solution reads

Full solution then
$$y=\tfrac{A}{a} x^n K_n\left(\sqrt{k} x\right)$$

Comment: It's brilliant! I believe this is what I am looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

> Can you please show your method?

Too large to post as comment. will remove this if not useful.  Basically, just solved the ode with `b` in place of `infinity` (with the idea of later taking the limit as b->infinity).

Then simplified the result with assumption `d>2` which gives zero. No need to take limit. If `d` is not larger than `2`, solution as given by Mathematica is not defined, since the solution to the ode has terms that look like

```
     0^(1/2 (-2 + d))
```

Which is not defined unless the power is positive (i.e. d>2) . And then it is zero. Here is the code

```
ClearAll[y, x, d, a, k, b];
ode = y''[x] + (d - 1)*y'[x]/x == k*y[x];
ic = {y[0] == a, y[b] == 0};
sol = y[x] /. First@DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now

```
 Assuming[d > 2, Simplify[sol]]
 (* 0 *)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for showing me the method. I think that the `0^(1/2 (-2 + d))` term might be due to the `(d-1)/x` term in the original equation, which makes the boundary condition of  `y[x=0]=a` invalid. I can get a numerical solution by changing the boundary condition to `y[x=0.0001]=a`. So I would like to ask if it is also possible to use limit to indicate this first boundary condition (the second boundary condition with infinity x position remains the same) so that the analytical solution can be defined with 0<d<1?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to solve the ode for general `d` between `0` and `1`, but it is possible to get a solution for a particular `d`.  For example I will use `d = 1/2`.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

ode = y''[x] + ((d - 1) Derivative[1][y][x])/x - k y[x] == 0 /. d -> 1/2
```

Using the finite bc's as a first pass is a good idea.

```
bc = {y[0] == a, y[b] == 0}

DSolve[{ode, bc}, y[x], x] // Flatten // Simplify

y[x_] = y[x] /. %
```

We get some complexes that we don't want so go through some simplification routines.

```
y[x_] = Simplify[FunctionExpand[y[x]], k > 0]

y[x_] = PowerExpand[% // Expand]

$Assumptions = k > 0
```

The above assumption is necessary to get the limit as `b -> \[Infinity]`

```
y[x_] = Limit[y[x], b -> \[Infinity]]
(*(2^(1/4) a k^(3/8) x^(3/4) BesselK[3/4, Sqrt[k] x])/Gamma[3/4]*)
```

Again, this solution is only valid for `d =1/2`.

Check the solution.

```
ode // FullSimplify
(*True*)

Limit[y[x], x -> 0]
(*a*)

Limit[y[x], x -> \[Infinity]]
(*0*)
```

Example plot

```
Plot[y[x] /. {a -> 1, k -> 1}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]